# Difference between positive and negative LCD drive

Tags: glcd

I have a positive type custom ordered LCD with 60 segments.

Display type: Reflective
Duty: 1/4
Bias: 1/3

Now, i want to replace the positive LCD with negative type.

The LCD is presently driven directly by the micro controller. (MCU has dedicated LCD driver, SEG and COM pins, direct connections).

**Question:**

Do i have to change anything in the MCU firmware?
I believe i need not. Except the addition of back light control, because it is a negative mode display.

Comment: If I understand correctly by what you describe as negative LCD, I suspect the only difference is the orientation of the polarising filter on the display.

Comment: @Roger yes. and the addition of backlight.. Does it automatically change the type of LCD to transmissive?

Comment: To answer your question, it's probably best to compare the two datasheets to establish if firmware changes are necessary. My guess would be no, but guessing is not engineering.

Comment: Well they will certainly know more than anyone here can tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received the response from one of the LCD manufacturer. According to them

> the LCD interface will remain the same irrespective of Positive or
>   Negative LCD.